# Selection of Array depending on variable in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, reflection, hashmap

I am sure that this post silly, while I need still some practical ideas. I have 20 `double[]` arrays named like `colVal1`, `colVal2`,... Now I have 5 variables say `que1`, `que2`, `que3`, `que4`, `que5` which contain integers from 1 to 20. I want to use arrays depending on the value contained in `que`*i*. Means if `que1` contains `3` then I like to use `colval3` in calculation. Manual use is avoidable due permutations of 20 numbers in 5 variables. Google hints that Java, in principle avoid replacement of variable name by another variable. I am lost at using `HashMap`. I could not use Reflection APIs correctly due to my limited knowledge base. Any handle is welcome. 
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to use an array I assume, so use an array of arrays.

```
double[][] colVal = new double[21][];
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    double[] row = colVal[i];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Note: this might be simpler if you started at 0 for the first row, instead of 1. i.e. you wouldn't need the unused row at the start.